# Remainder when dividing power series

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I know how long division of polynomials works. For example I can use it to divide $x^2+1$ into $x$ to get
$$x=(x^2+1)\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}$$
with remainder $R=-1/x$, so that
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1/x}{x^2+1}.$$
My question is, suppose $f$ and $g$ have infinite power series. I have seen people perform long division to compute $f/g$ up to the term, say, $x^4$, and what they say is that, up to that term, $\frac{f}{g}$ is whatever the quotient is up to that order. But what about the remainder? Is that zero?

Answer (score 1):

No, the remainder is not $0$, but another power series. For example,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
&=\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+O\!\left(x^9\right)}{1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+O\!\left(x^8\right)}\\[6pt]
&=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}+O\!\left(x^9\right)
\end{align}
$$
where the latter $O\!\left(x^9\right)$ is the series for
$$
\tan(x)-\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}\right)
$$
However, in the terminology for long division, the *remainder* would be
$$
\sin(x)-\cos(x)\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}\right)
$$
which is another power series.

However, when dealing with power series, it is often useful, and usually simpler, to use [Landau "big-O" notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are lucky enough that $f$ is a multiple of $g$ there is a remainder, but it is often ignored.  I just took an example with finite series that go out to $x^6$.  Any more terms will not impact the quotient up to order $x^6$  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6)%2F(1%2B2x%2B4x%5E2%2B3x%5E3%2B2x%5E4%2B3x%5E5%2B6x%5E6)) tells us that $$\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6}{1+2x+4x^2+3x^3+2x^4+3x^5+6x^6}=1 - x - x^2 + 4 x^3 - 2 x^4 + O(x^5)$$
If $x$ is rather small, terms in $x^5$ and higher will have little impact so we can choose to ignore them.